# Laravel is Redirecting to login after being logged with Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, middleware

Whey I login in laravel with ajax , i get success response, and after that i make a get request from the success section by calling a methode to fetch some shops data, then it redirect to the login page (like if I am not logged in) 
In postman this works perfectly even weather my routes are inside or outside the auth middleware
( I'm using external single html file instead of laravel views )
Here is my code : 1 - web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web'], function () {

  Route::get( 'shops/likedshops/', 'ShopUserController@liked_shopes' );

  Route::resource( 'shops', 'ShopController', [
    'except' => [
        'create',
        'store',
        'edit',
        'update',
        'destroy'
    ]
  ] );

  Route::resource( 'shopusers', 'ShopUserController', [
    'except' => [
        'create',
        'show',
        'edit',
    ]
  ]);
 });
```

2 : ShopUserController.php

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Jobs\DeleteDislikedShop;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\ShopUser;
 use App\User;
 use Auth;
 class ShopUserController extends Controller
 {
      // .... 
      public function liked_shopes(){
         $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
         $user = User::find($user_id);
         $shops = $user->shops()->where('is_liked', 1)->paginate(12);
         return response()->json(compact('shops'));
      }
  }
```

3 : app.js for my html file

```
$('.form-signin').on('submit',function (e){
    var email = $('#email-log').val()
    var password = $('#pass-log').val()       
    e.preventDefault(); 
    login(email, password); // <--------- Login
    return false;
});

function login(email, password) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login',
        data: {'email': email, 'password': password},
        success: function(response){
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.success.token);
            preferred_shops();  // <--------- Login
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert('Email and/or Password Incorrect');
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
function preferred_shops(page_number = 1) {
    $('#preferred-shops').remove();
    $('#nearby-shops').remove();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/shops/likedshops',
        data: {'page' : page_number},
        headers: {"Authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')}, // This isn't helping
        success: function(response){
            var data = response.shops.data;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
}
```

Comment: Double check your dev console, is your session cookie being set and then sent with your next request?  Also double check the cookie's domain.  If you're using an authorization token, make sure that's actually being sent with the request, perhaps drop some dd() or echo statements to make sure these values are coming through.

Comment: you'll need to get a new token from the server after you login

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you are sending a CSRF token, see docs below for how to implement this with an AJAX request:

[X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)